# How to read large text file line by line and process it?

Tags: python, word2vec

The file looks like this

```
   637   C0205088:Terminal (End-stage) [Qualitative Concept]
   637   C0439095:Alpha (Greek letter alpha (qualifier value)) [Intellectual Product]
   840   C0596072:amino group [Inorganic Chemical]
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
with open(r"filepath" , 'rb') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: Hello Amit,i tried this only but when in server to train word2vec it takes all RAM memory.  Can yield help? Is there any way to do without loading into memory?

Comment: try updated code in answer